# How to work with recursion output in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tuples

I am using recursion to run through a binary tree to get all the nodes at the end. That's working fine, the problem is, depending on the height of my tree I get tuples inside of tuples inside of tuples. How do i work with such output?

```
def minimax(tree):
    l = minimax_rec(tree.root)


    print(len(l))

def minimax_rec(curr):
    if curr.is_terminal():
        return curr.val
    else:
        if curr.val == -1:
            return minimax_rec(curr.left),minimax_rec(curr.mid),minimax_rec(curr.right)
        else:
            return curr.val, minimax_rec(curr.left),minimax_rec(curr.mid),minimax_rec(curr.right)
```

If the height of the tree is 3 I get something like this:

```
(((9, 37, 5), (17, 8, 32), (29, 31, 25)), ((14, 7, 32), (2, 25, 28), (39, 1, 29)), ((18, 15, 38), (7, 21, 2), (2, 2, 35)))
```

As the height of the tree increases so does the output and there's massive number of nested tuples. Is there a way to only get the tuples which contain values like this?

```
((9, 37, 5), (17, 8, 32), (29, 31, 25), (14, 7, 32), (2, 25, 28), (39, 1, 29), (18, 15, 38), (7, 21, 2), (2, 2, 35))
```

Comment: Create a `result` list in `minimax` and hand them down through the recursions as additional parameter of `minimax_rec`. Append each matching tuple to the list. If the recursions end, the list is ready for further use.

Answer (score -1):

As I don't know what your tree or curr looks like,the code may looks a little stupid

```
def minimax(tree):
    def minimax_rec(curr):
        if curr.is_terminal():
            return curr.val
        else:
            if curr.val == -1:
                result = minimax_rec(curr.left),minimax_rec(curr.mid),minimax_rec(curr.right)
                if isinstance(result[0], int):
                    result_list.append(result)
                return result
            else:
                return curr.val,minimax_rec(curr.left),minimax_rec(curr.mid),minimax_rec(curr.right)
    result_list = []
    l = minimax_rec(tree.root)
    print(result_list)
    print(len(l))
```

Comment: Your `result_list` is local to `minimax` and hence unavailable in `minimax_rec`.

Comment: when func minimax_rec can't find this variable,it can search in the space of outer minimax

Comment: Only if it’s nested inside the other function…

Comment: @DavisHerring  I have fixed this anwser, now is it right?

Comment: I can’t really tell: the ternary tree, apparent uniform depth, and coded-but-absent 4-tuple results are too strange for me to evaluate completely.